# How do I add the bin subdirectory of the first directory in GOPATH to PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

`echo $GOPATH` will print:

```
/mnt/star/program/go/package:/mnt/star/git_repository/workspace/go_workplace
```

There are 2 directories, I want to append the first directory's sub-directory `bin/` to `$PATH`.

If I write `$PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin`, then actually it appends 2 directories to `$PATH`:

- `/mnt/star/program/go/package`
  This only contains directories, it should be `/mnt/star/program/go/package/bin`.
- `/mnt/star/git_repository/workspace/go_workplace/bin`
  This actually shouldn't be added to `$PATH`.

BTW, there are cases that `$GOPATH` only contains one directory, so that simply appending `$GOPATH/bin` will work.

I am looking for a solution that fits both cases. So, how do I write this in a bash config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
PATH="$PATH:${GOPATH%%:*}/bin"
```

Or

```
PATH="$PATH:${GOPATH%:*}/bin"
```

Both will work because there can be at most one `:`.

It will remove the part after `:`. So, in your first case, it will remove the second directory and in your second case, there will be no pattern like `:*`, so there will be no change in the directory name.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! Only improvement this could get is default to `~/go` if not defined (which is default since Go 1.8 I believe) but this answers the asked question perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

```
PATH="$PATH:${GOPATH%%:*}/bin"
```

The asterisk is a glob, not a regular expression.  Two percentage signs means to remove the maximum that it can match from the back, so even if there were three or more directories, you would only get the first one.

If there's nothing to remove, it doesn't remove anything, so you get the only path if there's only one.

Comment: It's the opposite... It's supposed to *keep* the first part, so you need to *remove* the last part. This is definitely the best answer, so if you fix it to `PATH=$PATH:${GOPATH%%:*}/bin` I'll definitely upvote it!

Comment: I read the question backwards.  You're right, @filbranden.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an alternative answer using arrays; unfortunately this requires two steps to assign to the answer but I mention it anyway since it’s more general and potentially more versatile than the other answers:

```
IFS=: read -ra arr_gopath <<< "$GOPATH"
PATH="$PATH:${arr_gopath[0]/%//bin}"
```

The advantage with this approach is that you can easily specify any component of the `GOPATH`, not just the first one. Or, to append *all* elements, followed by `/bin`, to `PATH`:

```
PATH="$PATH:$(IFS=:; echo "${arr_gopath[*]/%//bin}")"
```

In both cases (splitting, joining) we set the internal field separator (`IFS`) to the colon character `:`. The substitution `${var/%//bin}` appends `/bin` to the end of a chosen variable.

That said, if you wanted to append *all* `GOPATH` components, suffixed with `/bin`, to the `PATH` then the following would be simpler and doesn’t require arrays. It does, however, require that `GOPATH` is not empty:

```
PATH="$PATH:${GOPATH//://bin}/bin"
```

(`${var//pattern/subst}` replaces *all* occurrences of `pattern` with `subst`, while `${var/pattern/subst}`, used above, only replaces the first one.)